# Keychain - OSStatus return -34018

Tags: ios, swift

iam trying save a value to Keychain. Code is right, but OSStatus returns code -34018.
In other project same code works right.

Code:

```
    fileprivate func save(key: String, value: String) -> Bool {
    guard let data: Data = value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
        return false
    }
    let query = [
        kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword as String,
        kSecAttrAccount as String: key,
        kSecValueData as String: data,
        ] as [String : Any]

    SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary)

    let status: OSStatus = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
    return status == noErr
}
```

Any idea, please?
Is there any  error with project settings or?

Comment: Internal error when a required entitlement isn't present. https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-34018

Comment: thanks. It was because my Keychain sharing in Capabilities was turn off :)

Comment: @ankmara, Thanks for your solution, but still i am getting stuck in Assertion failed: (osrc == noErr), function -[SCCSR build:privateKey:], file /Users/sujay/Desktop/GenerateCSR/GenerateCSR/SCCSR.m, line 86. Can you please guide.